# Pandas group by and row count by category

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df as follows:

```
User   Amount   Type
100     10      Check
100     20      Cash
100     30      Paypal
200     50      Venmo
200     50      Cash
200     50      Check
300     20      Zelle
300     15      Zelle
300     15      Zelle
```

I want to organize it such that my end result is as follows:

```
User     Cash     Check  Paypal   Venmo  Zelle
100       1        1      1
200       1        1                1
300                                        3
```

I am looking to count the number of times a user has transacted through each unique method.
If a user didnt transact, I want to either leave it blank or set it to 0.
How can I do this? I tried a `pd.groupby()` but am not sure of the next step...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(df['User'], df['Type']).reset_index().rename_axis('',axis=1)
```

output:

```
   User  Cash  Check  Paypal  Venmo  Zelle
0   100     1      1       1      0      0
1   200     1      1       0      1      0
2   300     0      0       0      0      3
```